# power bi : cloned report not showing data in visualizations

Tags: rest, powerbi

I am new to PowerBI and trying to copy/clone an existing report to new one with new dataset.

Here is the scenario:

- I already have a report and dataset imported with .pbix file.
- Now, I got new csv data, and I have created entirely new dataset using REST api.
- At this point, I want to **copy existing report and point it to newly created dataset**.

I have tried following approaches:

- Clone Report with new dataset:

  - used clone report api with `datasetId` pointing to new data set
- Clone Report and then Rebind:

  - used clone report api without `datasetId` param
  - used Rebind api to bind newly cloned report to new dataset

However, with both of above, the report or its visualisations are not populated. It is showing error `Something's wrong with one or more fields`.

Here is how the cloned report looks:

[image: Here is how the cloned report looks]

I have been struggling with this since couple of days.

Thanks for help in adv.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using below mentioned approach.

Posting it here so that someday it will help someone.

tl;dr:-> clone source report via api with new dataset, then manually fix the cloned report visualisations, and then use this fixed report as source for cloning as and when required.

---

Clone report approach worked for me:

1. Let's assume we have a source report say 'ReportA' linked to dataset 'DatasetA'.
2. Now, create a new app workspace say 'WS_B'.
3. Create a new dataset in WS_B with name 'DatasetB' having tables similar to 'DatasetA'
4. Clone report 'ReportA' into 'WS_B' with new dataset 'DatasetB', using [clone_report_api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clonereport). Call cloned report as 'ReportB'
5. After cloning, manually edit the ReportB and fix the visualisations by setting correct legends, values, x & y axis sources, etc. And, save the report.
6. Now, in your subsequent cloning usecases, use this 'ReportB' report as source report with new datasets created by apis.
7. With this, you will get a working cloned report, without any manual intervention anymore.